# how do I edit/customize tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to edit the tooltip so that I can have unique names for each point on a figure.  I'm trying the below code, but it wont work.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57mqsv6g/1/

```
tooltip: 
{
    formatter: function() {
        return 'The value for <b>' + this.x + '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>, in series '+ this.series.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't contain any formatter JS code, but if I add it, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that it works now, but it only returns the x and y values, not the third value (z)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/57mqsv6g/14/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Apples"
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Protein"
            }
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return 'The value for <b>' + this.x + '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>, in series '+ this.series.name;
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [[97, 36, 79], [94, 74, 60], [68, 76, 58], [64, 87, 56], [68, 27, 73], [74, 99, 42], [7, 93, 87], [51, 69, 40], [38, 23, 33], [57, 86, 31]]
        }, {
            data: [[25, 10, 87], [2, 75, 59], [11, 54, 8], [86, 55, 93], [5, 3, 58], [90, 63, 44], [91, 33, 17], [97, 3, 56], [15, 67, 48], [54, 25, 81]]
        }, {
            data: [[47, 47, 21], [20, 12, 4], [6, 76, 91], [38, 30, 60], [57, 98, 64], [61, 17, 80], [83, 60, 13], [67, 78, 75], [64, 12, 10], [30, 77, 82]]
        }]
    });
});
```

To access z in the formatter function use this.point.z. This is how this looks in the formatter:

[image: formatter context]

Comment: Thanks.  I see that it works now, but it only returns the x and y values, not the third value (z)...

Comment: That is why you are the expert.  Thank you!

Comment: How do I mention that your solution was helpful?